# How to run a c# Database application on other PCs?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

How can I connect a c# application which contains a database on another pc that doesn't have SQL SERVER Instance (.SQLEXPRESS) installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It cannot be possible.

But, you can use [SQl SERVER COMPACT EDITION](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact).

`Sql Server Compact Edition` allows you to *create* a *local database* that can be accessed **without** `sql server`